# Use complex algebra to rewrite a question

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Quick math question I'm struggling with:

I'm supposed to rewrite $(\cos(\theta))^3$ in terms of $\cos(3\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ using complex algebra.

I remember learning (but forgot why) that:
 $$\cos(3\theta)= (\cos(\theta))^3 - \cos(\theta)\times3(\sin(\theta))^2$$

And then I can rearrange that, but how do I use complex algebra? And how do I replace the $\sin(\theta)^2$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don’t forget that $\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)$. But I think they want you to use the fact that $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^3 = \cos 3\theta + i\sin 3\theta$. Expand the left-hand side, then compare real components.

Comment: Oh man! Is this De Moivres Theorem? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Nova Indeed it is—glad to help! Notice that you can easily extend this to higher powers to get similar results.